# Importing Github Library and Only Work With Library

Tags: android, eclipse, git, github, import

To make it clear, I'm aware on how to import a library from github to my eclipse workspace and that isn't the  problem.

I'm trying to import https://github.com/MartinvanZ/Inscription. If one were to look at the library, you'd see that the actual library isn't in the root but in a seperate folder.

Example:

```
Git Library
    library(folder)
    sample(folder)
    random files (licence, readme, etc)
```

I just want to import the library folder as a android project and then modify it and when I push it to the repo, it just gets pushed to the library folder.

How do I do this? If not possible, what can I do similar to what I want?

Comment: Your post sounds like you know how to do it but you are asking us anyway. You need to clarify that part. What do you know how to do? What have you tried? And what are you trying to do.

Comment: @Spundun I don't know how to do it, thats why I was asking

Comment: if you don't know how to do it then you shouldn't say "I'm aware on how to import a library from github to my eclipse..."

Comment: @Spundun I'm aware on how to import a library but I'm asking on how to import a specific part of the library and after modification, commit the changes to the specific part of the library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the problem here is that the library in question does not contain the files required to be imported directly as an Eclipse project. Specifically, it is missing `.project` and `.classpath` files. To get this project into Eclipse, you'll have to create a new project. Select File -> New -> Android Project and the pick the option that says "Create project from existing source."

This should create the required `.project` and `.classpath` files, without harming the .git directory.